# How to see the current dpkg-reconfigure value

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-environments

So i want to change the desktop manager using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure newmanagername`, but before that I want to know what is the current value used there. How do I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a way to query for specific keys, but you can dump all the selections and use grep e.g.

```
$ sudo debconf-get-selections | grep display-manager
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager    select  lightdm
```

Alternatively, if you can guess which package is currently configured you can confirm with `debconf-show`

```
$ sudo debconf-show lightdm
* shared/default-x-display-manager: lightdm
```

However you should be able to get the same information by looking in the `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Comment: I may be horribly wrong, but I think it should be `debconf get-selections` (without hyphen) I get 'command not found' whereas if I take out the hyphen it just complains about some missing database (presumably because I'm using MATE... unless I have a problem!)

Comment: @Zanna hmm... I copy-pasted it directly from my 14.04 box: `debconf-get-selections` seems to be provided by the `debconf-utils` package (maybe that's not installed by default?)

Comment: `sudo debconf-get-selections` doesn't work in Lubuntu 16.04 also. Maybe a Unity feature? But `sudo debconf-show` works.

Comment: oh right - I have `debconf` (1.5.58ubuntu1) but not `debconf-utils` (candidate: 1.5.58ubuntu1 - so clearly related). Maybe it is installed by default in Ubuntu (not MATE) `debconf-show` does exist (but complains about missing files again) Edit: I installed `debconf-utils` and now it works great - very useful ^_^

Comment: sudo debconf-get-selections doesn't work for me either (ubuntu 114.04) but the cat  /etc/X11/default-display-manger is what i was looking for i guess. thanks